# Using TypeScript + Lodash, how do you push something into an array?

Tags: typescript

```
const initialState: FriendsState = {
  friends: []
};

export default function friends(state = initialState, action: Action): FriendsState {
  switch (action.type) {
    case TYPES.ADD_TO_FRIENDS:
      return assign({}, state, {
        friends: state.friends.push(action.payload.friendId)
      })
  }
}
```

I am basically trying to add a `friendId` that looks like something like 1003 or something into my friends array.  Is that the right way of going about it?

What about if I have to add an object?  something like `{ friendId: 1003, category: 4 }`

```
export interface Friends {
  friends: FriendIds[];
};

interface FriendIds {
  id: number;
}
```

Comment: i get an error that says `TypeError: state.friends.push is not a function`

Comment: Then I suppose it's not an array as you assumed. Remember also that `push` does not return the resulting array, so in some cases you may want to use `concat`.

Comment: I think I am defining my array wrong then.  Can you please take a look at my edit?

Comment: The first push will rewrite `friends` to an integer (which is what `push` returns). Then the second push will fail, because you can't push to an integer.

Comment: thanks i now understand concat vs push better !!

Answer (score 2):

> I am basically trying to add a friendId that looks like something like 1003 or something into my friends array. Is that the right way of going about it

Yes `push` will add to the array.

However it mutates the array. Seeing as you are using Redux (docs : http://redux.js.org/) you want to use non mutating methods. e.g concat:

```
const initialState: FriendsState = {
  friends: []
};

export default function friends(state = initialState, action: Action): FriendsState {
  switch (action.type) {
    case TYPES.ADD_TO_FRIENDS:
      return assign({}, state, {
        friends: state.friends.concat([action.payload.friendId])
      })
  }
}
```